# Can't Access Subdomain from localhost

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two sites hosted on the same Linus VPS. When I try to connect to one site from the other via curl I get an empty response. I can connect from any other of my test servers without issue. I both sub-domains are resolving to the correct IPs. The Apache access log shows a 404 error for each of the failed calls. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First, is the IP Address bound to your server or via NAT on a private IP.

If it's a private IP you need to either do split dns (you can add a /etc/hosts record) or install a local dns server like bind and setup the local domain to point to the local server.

You can test it with this:

`curl --header 'Host: www.example.com' 'http://127.0.0.1'`

for additional help please post output of your `ip addr` or `ifconfig

Comment: I tested both sub-domains with the curl line you provided. I get the basic Apache start up page for both. This is starting to sound a little above my skill set. Thanks for your help, but I think i'll have to wait for my server admin to show up tomorrow.